# Sony ILCE-QX1 camera, image size during remote capture with no memory card

Tags: camera, sony

When remotely capturing still images using 'actTakePicture', on the Sony ILCE-QX1 camera it is possible to remotely capture and obtain images when no memory card in inserted.

However, the captured image size is this case is only 1616x1080, whereas if the memory card is inserted full image size 5456x3632 is obtained.

"setStillSize",is set to ["3:2","20M"], and  "setPostviewImageSize" is set to "Original" - but this does not seem to have any effect when the memory card is not present.

The reason I would like to shoot without card (or without saving to card) is to save the time it takes to same the image to the card.

Q: is it at all possible to capture full image size with no card or without saving to the card on the Sony ILCE-QX1? (perhaps internal memory is not sufficient although it seems strange as burst mode typically uses internal memory), and if so how?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately is it not possible to capture a full size image without a memory card on the QX1.

Comment: thanks!
Is there a way to delete all content or to format card 
Or to delete the file just captured (I have its URL, not its URI) via SDK?

When memory card gets full, it is again no longer possible to capture  full size images

Comment: Yes, take a look at the deleteContent API.

Comment: Getting a "No Such Method" Error: {u'id': 1, u'error': [12, u'deleteContent']}
I assume I need to update my firmware, but I don't know how 
(The FAQ in support sends to Camera Instruction Manual - but couldn't find firmware update instruction in Sony ILCE-QX1 instruction manual.

Comment: There is currently no firmware update available for the QX1.  Did you ensure that you are using the /avContent endpoint?  Also see the note in the documentation below: This API can be called only when "cameraStatus" of "getEvent" is "ContentsTransfer". After calling this API, the camera status will be changed to "Deleting". And the status will be back to "ContentsTransfer" after deletion is done.